# Validation Groups for Subforms in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony5

Seems that the validation group applied to a subform is ignored by the validation in the parent form.

**My subform:**
PasswordUpdate
Pass1 -> NotBlank ['groups'->'password_update']
Pass2

For the subform, this is the configureOptions:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form){
                $validation_group = [];
                if ($form->get('password_update')->getData()){
                    $validation_group = ['Default', 'password_update'];
                }else{
                    $validation_group =  ['Default'];
                }
                return $validation_group;
            }
            ]);
    }
```

**MainForm**

Name
Subform

For the Mainform, this is the configureOptions:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Profesor::class,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'validation_groups' => false,
       ]);
    }
```

Even that the validation_groups is set to FALSE, the form is throwing errors in the subform.

How do i apply validation groups to a subform??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `buildForm` method of the parent form you forward the options to the sub form, like this:

```
->add('subForm', SubformType::class, [
    'validation_groups' => $options['validation_groups'],
    // your other options
])
```

It actually is not preferrable for the form component "framework" to forward options by default because it can have unintended consequences, so explicitly forwarding options is the way to go (imagining an unintentionally evil counter example won't be really hard, I presume).

Comment: I think i didn't make may self clear.  The problem is that even when I set _validation_groups_ to false in main and sub form, the validation of the fields in subform take place.

Comment: Seems that the problem is in the declaration of validation_group for each field in the subform. I removed that and only leave groups for each contraint and worked.  Thank you. Your answer took me in the right direction.